# Remove / deactivate Polymer observers

Tags: polymer, messaging, observer-pattern

So I've decided to try using [observers](https://www.polymer-project.org/0.5/docs/polymer/polymer.html#observeblock) instead of [custom events](https://www.polymer-project.org/0.5/articles/communication.html#events) for communication.

In my bootstrap logic, I'm listening for some models to update with an observe block:

```
observe: {
  '$.myModel.value': function(){
      initLogic();
      delete this.observe['$.myModel.value']; 
   }
},
```

Then I want to stop listening because this only needs be done once.

Is it as simple as deleting the `observe.<whatever>` function (as shown above) or **do I need to be more explicit** with Polymer?

Alternatively I can use a promise, in which case I don't care if the observer keeps triggering:

```
var initDeferred = Promise.defer();
Polymer('init-logic', {
    observe: {
        '$.myModel.value': initDeferred.resolve
    },
    ready: function(){
        initDeferred.promise.then(initLogic);
    }
});
```

But **is there a performance impact** for having unnecessary observers in place?

Answer (score 1):

Look into this link https://www.polymer-project.org/0.5/docs/polymer/binding-types.html#one-time-bindings
I am not sure if this will help in your case or not.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, I hadn't noticed but I'm not sure how I can use bindings in place of observers/event listeners. I was also thinking about extending Polymer elements with an `observeOnce` feature in the style of [onMutations](https://www.polymer-project.org/0.5/docs/polymer/polymer.html#onMutation) but that would work on attributes instead of DOM subtree.

Comment: From what I understand, myModel need to be set once, right? So you can pass the value of this myModel in an attribute of the element, but using one time binding syntax for myModel in you code. Although, i havent tried it even once, but this is how I would have proceed.

Comment: I see what you mean, but it would only work with primitive type values, not for objects or functions.

Comment: yes, it wont work on objects or functions. But you can use the following

`Polymer('init-logic', {
    observe: {
        'myModel.someVar': 'updateStuff'
    },
    updateStuff: function(){
        //stuff u want to do
    }
});`

Comment: This is equivalent to the OP, the `updateStuff` function will keep triggering at every change.